# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan^2x-x^2}{x^2\tan^2x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

I would like to evaluate the following limit:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan^2x-x^2}{x^2\tan^2x}$$

I tried breaking the limit as:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\tan^2x}\right)$$

Writing tan is terms of sin and cos, this becomes:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2x×x^2/x^2}\right)$$

Using standard limit of $\sin x/x$, we obtain:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos^2x}{x^2}$$

Since $1-\cos^2x=\sin^2x$, using standard limits again we get 1 as the answer. But the correct answer is $2/3$. Please explain what is going wrong.

Comment: Limit algebra (eg: the breaking step) is only valid when the broken limits exist by themself. Also this quesiton has been asked more than million times on this site.

Comment: Understood, thank you!

Comment: To be specific, the problem is not in the first step (“breaking”), since the limit there is still taken on the whole expression. It's rather with the step where the subexpression $\sin(x)/x \to 1$. You can't let *some* $x$ tend to zero while keeping *other* $x$ untouched, since *all* occurrences of $x$ stand for the same number!

Comment: The mistake is when replacing a subexpression with its limit:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{\cos^2x}{x^2\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^2}\right)\ne\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{\cos^2x}{x^2\left(1\right)^2}\right).$$
Such a mistake is more visible in the following:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac xx\ne\lim_{x\to0}\frac0x$$ ($1\ne0$).

Comment: Hint: use difference of squares to express in terms of $\tan x/x$ and $(\tan x - x)/x^3$, whose limits both exist as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Thanks, makes a lot more sense now

Comment: Good point @HansLundmark